# Number formatting in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have an dictionary as follows:

```
{'warranty': '1 jaar', 'delivery': u'2017-06-13', 'to_pay': 9000.0, 'deposit': 1000.0}
```

I send it to Django template and I want to show `to_pay` as `9.000,00`. But I can't.

I have

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load l10n %}
```

at the top of the template and I have

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

in settings.py

What have I tried:

```
{{ car.sale.to_pay|floatformat:2|intcomma }} // 9,000,00
{{ car.sale.to_pay|intcomma }} // 9.000,0  almost good, but I need two zeroes after comma
{{ car.sale.to_pay|localize }} // 9000,0
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why not converting the floats in your dictionary in a strings and add zeros as you want ?

Comment: For example `{k: '{:.2f}'.format(v) if isinstance(v, float) else v for k,v in your_dict.items()}` Then pass your dict data into your template as str.

Answer (score 3):

#### Custom Template Filter

You can always create your own template filter to get the desired result. Here's an implementation that uses intcomma to format the number to your desired result

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def my_float_format(number, decimal_places=2, decimal=','):
    result = intcomma(number)
    result += decimal if decimal not in result else ''
    while len(result.split(decimal)[1]) != decimal_places:
        result += '0'
    return result
```

Then to use in a template

```
{% load my_tags %}
{{ 450000.0|my_float_format }}
```

Renders this

```
450.000,00
```

---

#### Old Answer (Incorrect)

You can use the `stringformat` filter to use basic python string formatting first and get the desired number of decimal places, then pass it through `intcomma` to get the number formatting.

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ car.sale.to_pay|stringformat:'0.2f'|intcomma }}
```

Comment: This way I get `9,000.00` instead of `9.000,00`

Comment: Closer, haha. What if you use `localize` instead of `intcomma`?

Comment: Then I get `9000.00` :)

Comment: @Boky this might be because of the language set in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/formatting/  it affects what intcomma does

Comment: I think I came up with a new solution up above.

Comment: In this `{% load my_tags %}` what is `my_tags` ?

Comment: Its the name of your templatetag library. `myapp/templatetags/my_tags.py`